# How to set log scaling axis in ParallelAxisPlot?

Tags: plotting

I'm using ParallelAxisPlot on the dataset ([download here](https://pastebin.com/raw/jHG5QMfb)).

On the 3rd and 4th axes, the data display is too crowded.

[image: pic]

So I want to use log scaling on these two axes.
However, I didn't find options in the documentation. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = Partition[{2., 20., 0.030852, 11.497, 2., 40., 0.0082219, 
   2.7289, 2., 60., 0.0045454, 2.3661, 2., 80., 0.0017867, 2.2378, 
   2., 100., 0.0021235, 1.8718, 2., 120., 0.0026967, 2.3964, 4., 20., 
   0.011798, 4.2635, 4., 40., 0.0027562, 2.3058, 4., 60., 0.0018687, 
   1.6324, 4., 80., 0.0011827, 1.5431, 4., 100., 0.0017416, 2.4224, 
   4., 120., 0.0015306, 1.4546, 6., 20., 0.0061146, 2.6876, 6., 40., 
   0.005244, 2.0673, 6., 60., 0.0020379, 1.3371, 6., 80., 0.0018589, 
   1.3257, 6., 100., 0.0025679, 1.5563, 6., 120., 0.0025159, 1.2078, 
   8., 20., 0.018569, 4.3973, 8., 40., 0.008022, 4.193, 8., 60., 
   0.0034943, 1.3709, 8., 80., 0.004054, 1.7686, 8., 100., 0.0065585, 
   2.5412, 10., 20., 0.015601, 5.5986, 10., 40., 0.0063813, 3.0787, 
   10., 60., 0.0044473, 1.9977, 10., 80., 0.0085365, 3.3273}, 4]

ParallelAxisPlot[data, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log10", "Log10"}]
```

[image]